# "advanced progressive" usable together?

Tags: meaning, american-english, spoken-english

I am a native German speaker and wanted to ask

1) if it is meaningful to use "advanced progressive", both words together
2) what is the exact meaning of these using in combination?

Context:

> "advanced progressive software systems"

Does it make sense?

Comment: I assume ***progressive** = favouring social reform*. If not, please explain what *you* want it to mean. I know they're making great strides in artificial intelligence these days, but I don't think there's anything like that in the world of software yet. Advanced *incremental* software??

Comment: I want the meaning like "future oriented, next, complex, highly developed software systems"

Comment: progressive can mean anything that moves forward in increments: this is probably not the sense that you want to give. If you want to say that you are doing stuff that has not been done before, you can  say that  it's leading edge, or at the cutting edge, or pushing back the boundaries.

Comment: These terms are nearly vacant.  "Advanced" is so overused in information systems that it is virtually meaningless in that context. For example, search for 'starting with'  **advanced** here: https://www.corporations.pa.gov/search/corpsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying 'advanced progressive' is overloading the phrase, in my opinion, since the two terms are expressing the same thing, i.e that this software is high tech.

If this was present in marketing text then you would convey the meaning you want, though it wouldn't sound great.

If I was editing this I would conjunct the two terms ("advanced and progressive software"). Either that or I would remove the word progressive, as it fits the meaning you are trying to convey less then the word advanced.